# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException when using DownloadManager on KitKat (endless progress)

Tags: android, ssl, tls1.2, android-4.4-kitkat, sslhandshakeexception

I'm trying to download files using the following code:

```
DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
DownloadManager.Request dRequest = new DownloadManager.Request(downloadUri);
downloadManager.enqueue(dRequest);
```

what happens?

**Devices > KitKat**

Everything works fine, i'm seeing the native notification correctly, progress is being update and the file is being download to the Download/ folder.

**Devices <= KitKat**

I'm seeing the native notification correctly, system tries to download the file but error happens. notification progress stays forever (infinite progress)

The error i'm seeing in logcat is:

```
W/DownloadManager: Aborting request for download 55: while trying to execute request: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x752e2028: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:741 0x621ebd38:0x00000000) FinalStatus = 495
```

Some insights:

- Tried to download sample zip file from device Chrome app and it didn't work also, until Google last update for Chrome.
- If i'm replacing https to http, it's working, but this is not good solution for me

**Thanks very much for the help!**

Comment: The (unknown) server you are trying to reach has likely disabled support for TLS 1.0 or uses ciphers not supported by the older Android versions. If you are in control of the server you need to configure it appropriately, if not you are out of luck.